# Create Google Form using Forms API, where is it stored?

Tags: python, google-forms, google-forms-api

I've been following a tutorial to create a Form from Python using the Forms API. I'm using a service account to create the form, and it does it alright. My question is: where is it stored? Does the service account have a Drive storage unit? If so, where can I see it?

On a similar note, can I create a Form using the Forms API in a specific folder?

Here's the code.

```py
from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body"
DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'credencial.json',
    SCOPES
)

http = creds.authorize(Http())

form_service = discovery.build(
    'forms',
    'v1',
    http=http,
    discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC,
    static_discovery=False
)

NEW_FORM = {
    "info":{
        "title": "Mi formulario"
    }
}

NEW_QUESTION = {
    "requests": [{
        "createItem": {
            "item": {
                "title": "¿Qué es una pregunta?",
                "questionItem": {
                    "question": {
                        "required": False,
                        "textQuestion": {
                            "paragraph": False
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "index": 0
            }
        }
    }]
}

result = form_service.forms().create(
    body = NEW_FORM
).execute()

question_setting = form_service.forms().batchUpdate(
    formId=result["formId"],
    body=NEW_QUESTION
).execute()

get_result = form_service.forms().get(
    formId=result["formId"]
).execute()

print(json.dumps(get_result, indent=4))
```

Tried the previous code, expected to find a Google Drive somewhere associated to the service account that was used to create the Form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Location of Google Drive Service Account Uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534822/location-of-google-drive-service-account-uploads)